# re-styling JQueryMobile for iphone webkit - to have text and textbox on same line

Tags: jquery-mobile

On the iphone I have a form:

I'd like to have:

```
from $37,400 up to $[textbox here]
```

on the same line. In landscape mode it works but not in portrait no matter how far I pare the text width. I'm searching for a style to override. You can simulate the problem by opening http://jsfiddle.net/mckennatim/xwFW9/1/ and narrowing your browser page way down.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title> - jsFiddle demo</title> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.0-rc.1/jquery.mobile-1.1.0-rc.1.min.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.0-rc.1/jquery.mobile-1.1.0-rc.1.min.js"></script>  

  <style type='text/css'>
    #upto4 {
        width: 65px;
        margin-left: 5px;
        margin-right: 5px;
    }
  </style>

<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[ 

</script>
</head>
<body>
<div data-role="page" id="calcs" data-add-back-btn="true">
    <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
        <h1>graphics2</h1>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">
    <form action="#" method="get">
        <div  id="ratelist">
            <legend><b>Ordinary Tax Rates</b></legend>
            <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                <input type="range" name="slider" id="rate4" value="30" min="0" max="100" data-highlight="true" data-mini="true" />
                    up to $: <br/>                           
                <p id="spupto4"> from $84,600 to
                    <input type="text" name="nupto4" id="upto4" value="178653" data-mini="true"/>                       
                </p><br/>
            </div>
            <div data-role="fieldcontain">              
                <label for="slider">% rate:</label>
                <input type="range" name="slider" id="rate5" value="33" min="0" max="70" data-highlight="true" data-mini="true" /><br/>
                <label for="slider">up to $</label>
                <input type="range" name="slider" id="upto5" value="388350" min="0" max="3000000" data-highlight="true" data-mini="true" /><br/>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
    </div>
    <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
        <h4>test</h4>
    </div>
</div> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I found it, needed to add display:inline-block; to override the display:block;. Sorry to have you read it, wish I could have just deleted the post.

Comment: post it as answer. you might increase ur score :)

Answer (score 0):

to the style:

```
<style type='text/css'>
  #upto4 {
    width: 65px;
    margin-left: 5px;
    margin-right: 5px;
}
```

added display: inline-block; to override display: block;

```
<style type='text/css'>
#upto4 {
    width: 65px;
    margin-left: 5px;
    margin-right: 5px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```